# ES6 rest parameters arguments example

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't really understand the below JavaScript example.

```
function containsAll(arr) {
  for (let k = 1; k < arguments.length; k++) {
    let num = arguments[k];
    if (arr.indexOf(num) === -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
let x = [2, 4, 6, 7];
console.log(containsAll(x, 2, 4, 7));
console.log(containsAll(x, 6, 4, 9));
```

The output is `1` and `0` in the console.

I'm trying to envision how it should work.

1. In this console.log(containsAll(x, 2, 4, 7)), the `x` should be replaced, changing it to console.log(containsAll(2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 4, 7)).
2. The `function containsAll` get those numbers (2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 4, 7).
3. In this line,  `for(let k = 1; k < arguments.length; k++)`, `k` should be a new array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], with the argument length which is the length of arr (in this case, 7 is the length), right?
4. In next step, which is `let num = arguments[k]; if (arr.indexOf(num) === -1) {return false;}` `let num` should be `num = 1`, right?
5. Then, in the if statement, it tests if `1` is in the array, arr = [2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 4, 7]. And if no match is found, it returns false. And it should repeat for the next number in the `arr` array, correct?

I'm just trying to figure out why it output `1` for `console.log(containsAll(x, 2, 4, 7));` when it should return something like `[false, true, false, true, false, true]`.

Comment: *"The output is 1 and 0 in the console."* WIth apologies, that seems really unlikely, as you're logging the result of calling a function that only returns `true` or `false`. Edit: And [sure enough](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/9xcy7s6z/), it logs `true` and `false`, not `1` and `0`.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with ES6 or rest parameters.

Comment: By far the best way to understand this code is to watch it run. Run it in the debugger built into your browser or IDE and step through the code statement by statement.

Comment: @Ivar - Indeed, and if you were using a rest parameter, you'd do this differently. My suspicion is that this is the "before" code of a before / after sequence. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. In this console.log(containsAll(x, 2, 4, 7)), the `x` should be replaced, changing it to console.log(containsAll(2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 4,
>      7)).

No, it stays `[2, 4, 6, 7], 2 ,4 ,7`

> 2. The `function containsAll` get those numbers (2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 4, 7).

It gets `[2, 4, 6, 7], 2 ,4 ,7`

> 3. In this line,  `for(let k = 1; k < arguments.length; k++)`, `k` should be a new array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], with the argument length
>      which is the length of arr (in this case, 7 is the length), right?

`k` is just a number representing the index inside `arguments` not an array.
The length is just 4, the array is just one element

> 4. In next step, which is `let num = arguments[k]; if (arr.indexOf(num) === -1) {return false;}` `let num` should be `num = 1`, right?

`num` iterates over the remaining elements of `arguments` (`2 ,4 ,7`). Notice the `k=1` in the for loop to skip the first element.

> 5. Then, in the if statement, it tests if `1` is in the array, arr = [2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 4, 7]. And if no match is found, it returns false. And
>      it should repeat for the next number in the `arr` array, correct?

It returns already if it finds the first match.

> I'm just trying to figure out why it output `1` for
>   `console.log(containsAll(x, 2, 4, 7));` when it should return
>   something like `[false, true, false, true, false, true]`.

When `return` is called the execution inside the method stops.

Comment: The [arguments Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is an object that you can access inside a function, which stores the arguments you pass to a function.

since your function definition contains only one parameter `containsAll(args)` , only the first value you passed to `containsAll([2,4,6,7] , 2 , 4 , 7)`  is stored to args.
And JS also stores all the arguments passed to `arguments` object.

Comment: arguments is actually an array

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel - `arguments` is actually **not** an array. It's an array-like exotic object.

Comment: oh okay, but normally(you shouldn't use it anyways) you use it like an array

Answer (score 0):

```
First, your code currently outputs `true` and `false` not 1 and 0.
The reason you don't have an array like this,[false, true, false, true, false, true], is because of the `return` keyword used in the conditional `if` statement inside your `for` loop.
```

The code below is one way to do it.

```
function containsAll(arr) {
  let result = []
  for (let k = 1; k < arguments.length; k++) {
    let num = arguments[k];
    if (arr.indexOf(num) === -1) {
      result.push(false);
    } else{
        result.push(true);
    }
  }
    return result;
}
let x = [2, 4, 6, 7];
console.log(containsAll(x, 2, 4, 7)); //Output [true, true, true]
console.log(containsAll(x, 6, 4, 9)); //Output [true, true, false]
```